# How to delete all occurences of a substring except the first one in any string

Tags: python

Given a string `text` and a proper substring `query`. How to delete all occurence of the query except the first one?

Example:

```
text = 'cccsumoxxxsumoppqqsumovvvvsumo' 
query = 'sumo' 

result: 'cccsumoxxxppqqvvvv'
```

Comment: Your question will be better received if you show some of your own coding efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `str.partition`:

```
def f(text, qry):
    pre, sep, suf = text.partition(qry)
    return pre + sep + suf.replace(qry, '')
```

This transparently handles cases where the query string may or may not exist and does the minimum necessary processing of the string (no counting of the query string or slicing etc...)

Answer (score 6):

Notice that `replace()` can specify a max count, thus you can exploit it with a little trick:

```
text[::-1].replace(query[::-1], '', text.count(query)-1)[::-1]
```

Comment: This is quite intelligent use of replace.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to do it:

```
''.join(text.rsplit(query, text.count(query) - 1))
```

This reverse splits `text` where `query` is found (thus removing it), except the last occurrence (hence `-1`), and then joins all split pieces.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do is using `slicing`.

```
text = 'cccsumoxxxsumoppqqsumovvvvsumo' 
query = 'sumo' 
first = text.index(query) + len(query)
text = text[:first] + text[first:].replace(query, "")
print(text)
```

Output:

```
cccsumoxxxppqqvvvv
```